# mount to webdav over terminal command with user credentials

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, webdav

I'm trying to mount to a webdav share over terminal on OS X. But it doesn't work very well.

`mount_webdav -i "http://<ip-address>:80/Path/" "/Path/To/mntpnt/"`

This is working, because it's prompting for username and password.

BUT!

`mount_webdav -i "mount_webdav "http://<windomain>;<username>:<Password>@<ip-address>:80/Path/" "/Path/To/mntpnt/"`

This command above don't work.

Have someone a good idea?

Is it possible to automate the `-i` command over a bash script?

Answer (score 0):

If you store your username and password into your OS X keychain, `mount_webdav` should automatically pick it up.

s a sidenote, I was under the impression that it's a bad idea to call `mount_webdav` directly, and you should go via `mount` instead. But it's possible that that's only true for linux.

Comment: I can't use the feature with the keychain, because it will work in business software.

Comment: Why does it matter how the software is used? Keychain will work for personal as well as business software =)